# How To Add Mail Compose View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, email

I have a UITable, when I click the cell called "Mail", I want it to push sendMailViewController.

In this sendMailViewController, in viewDidLoad I would call [self displayComposerSheet]:

Would this theoretically be the right way to go about this?

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Hello from California!"];

    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
    NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
    NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
    [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"rainy"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your didselectRow do for that indexpath.row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(indexPath.row==*give your row no*)
{

if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Hello from California!"];

    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
    NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
    NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
    [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"rainy"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];

        }
        else
        {
            //NSLog(@"Message cannot be sent");
        }
}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailController didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct but as a precaution you should add:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    ....your picker code...
}
else {
    // alert user that they can't send email?
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, so nothing to setup in IB, right?  and for the else, ill add `[self launchMailAppOnDevice];`. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you do not need to create another sendMailViewController. It is fine if you have but you could call 'displayComposerSheet' from within the -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {} The MFMailComposeViewController should display over your current view.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but I'd recommend you present the `MFMailComposeViewController` from your `UITableViewController`, rather than pushing a new view controller and presenting it there -- that'll probably end up looking strange and unnecessary.